# Cucumber and Rails - printing scenarios as they pass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, cucumber

I'm using Cucumber to test my Rails app. Is there anyway to print the scenario description as the tests run? Thanks!

Sample run:

```
laptop:rails_proj mark$ rake cucumber
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby -S bundle exec cucumber  --profile default
 Using the default profile...

 ........................................................................................

20 scenarios (20 passed)
88 steps (88 passed)
0m0.593s
Loaded suite /usr/bin/rake
Started

Finished in 0.000174 seconds.

0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's the --profile option. I have mine set to "dev_report".

See here:
https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/cucumber.yml

Comment: Oooh, I successfully answered a question that had nothing to do with PHP. It's a milestone!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Cucumber Rails gem ? It prints them by default for me...

Comment: Using: gem 'rspec-rails', '2.5.0' and 'cucumber-rails', '0.3.2'

Answer (score 0):

Can you post a sample of one of yours tests? The output shows "0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors" which sounds like they aren't doing anything.